# Very high CPU load (how to interpret output of "top"?)

Tags: linux

I am using Logstash to send logfiles via the Gelf plugin to Graylog2.

My config is fairly complex, with lots of grok filters.

When my system is under load the messages queue up for DAYS.

I have attached the output of "top".

- How do I interpret "[main]>worker0" - and what does "[main]

  I guess a constant 100% CPU load per worker is not good, no?

> ```
> top - 16:34:11 up 45 days, 22:56, 3 users, load average: 5.19, 5.74, 10.87
> Threads: 81 total, 4 running, 77 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
> %Cpu(s): 13.9 us, 0.4 sy, 84.9 ni, 0.3 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.4 si, 0.0 st
> KiB Mem : 15398116 total, 173912 free, 11405412 used, 3818792 buff/cache
> KiB Swap: 0 total, 0 free, 0 used. 3417404 avail Mem
>
> PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
> 27886 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 R 86.7 3.2 12850:42 [main]>worker0
> 27888 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 R 86.7 3.2 12853:13 [main]>worker2
> 27887 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 R 81.1 3.2 12849:42 [main]>worker1
> 27889 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 R 79.7 3.2 12857:18 [main]>worker3
> 27894 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 2.3 3.2 68:36.41 [main]<file
> 27890 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 1.0 3.2 64:45.88 [main]<file
> 27742 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 19:17.18 java
> 27743 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 19:23.35 java
> 27744 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 19:23.70 java
> 27745 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 19:27.28 java
> 27747 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 9:10.55 java
> 27757 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 11:35.33 java
> 27892 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 18:20.70 [main]<file
> 27895 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.3 3.2 11:16.33 [main]-pipeline
> 27706 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.0 3.2 0:00.00 java
> 27738 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.0 3.2 2:35.57 LogStash::Runne
> 27746 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.0 3.2 80:24.30 java
> 27748 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.0 3.2 0:11.65 java
> 27749 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.0 3.2 0:05.61 java
> 27751 logstash 39 19 4718860 492004 10596 S 0.0 3.2 0:00.17 java
> ...
> ```

Comment: I'm guessing main is the parent logstash thread, which has created the [4 workers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/execution-model.html). I don't think that having a thread at 100% CPU is a bad thing for logstash, but it might be a problem if you have other application running on the same machine. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/performance-troubleshooting.html might help you on the performance side of things.

Comment: Also, if you can, you should reduce the number of grok filter a message goes through, using tags and conditionals or grouping multiple patterns in one grok filter with the break on match option. And if you have the ressources (in term of machines), set a collector (filebeat or beaver) to send the files to a queue (like redis) then use more than one logstash to pull from the queue.

Comment: What does this "[main]>worker0" and the "[main]<file" mean?

Comment: Best guess: we got a thread main, created when launching logstash. Thread main created a thread for the file input: `[main]<file`, this thread tails the file and sends new lines as event to any worker which is free. Thread main created four worker threads: `[main]>worker0-3`, which are the thread processing each event, according to the logstash documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/execution-model.html

Comment: Don't get too hang up on the results of top, you'd be better served by understanding how logstash works and apply that understanding to improve your configuration.

Comment: At the moment I just don't know what the bottleneck is: (a) the receiving side (Graylog) - or (b) the sending side (Logstash). Is there a way to figure out how fast Logstash can produce messages? I assume the complex Logstash filter config is the problem.

Comment: To measure performance of the different of the receiving side, use a configuration with just the graylog input and a stdout output and count the number of message outputed over a set period of time. For the filter, use an stdin or file input with an input like what is received (you can reuse what you got when measuring the receiving) and use an output like stdout to measure the number of message over a period of time. This should allow to find where the bottleneck is. And then you'll have measures and not assumptions.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/tuning-logstash.html): "On Linux platforms, Logstash labels all the threads it can with something descriptive. For example, inputs show up as [base]<inputname, and pipeline workers show up as [base]>workerN, where N is an integer. Where possible, other threads are also labeled to help you identify their purpose."